# Grails Integration Test error A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have the following integration test:

```
@Integration
@Rollback

class IndustryDataServiceSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    Sector techSector
    Industry AI
    Industry HCI
    def industryDataService

    def setup() {

        techSector = new Sector(name: "Technology")
        techSector.save(flush: true)
        AI = new Industry(name: "Artificial Intelligence")
        HCI = new Industry(name: "HCI")
        techSector.addToIndustries(AI)
        techSector.addToIndustries(HCI)

    }

    def "attach the sector to the industry"() {

        when: "the industry is saved"

        def messageAI = industryDataService.insertIndustry(AI)
        def messageHCI = industryDataService.insertIndustry(HCI)

        then: "the industry should be saved and render the message"
        messageAI == AI.name + " has been saved"
        messageHCI == HCI.name + " has been saved"
    }

    def "get the industries which match the sector"() {
        given: "a sector name"
        String tech = "Technology"

        when: "get the industries"
        def industryList = industryDataService.getIndustriesToSector(tech)

        then: "only the industries which are within this sector should be returned"
        industryList.size == 2
    }

    def cleaup() {
        AI.delete(flush: true)
        HCI.delete(flush: true)
        techSector.delete(flush: true)
    }

}
```

The `industryDataService.insertIndustry` is the following:

```
def insertIndustry(Industry newIndustry) {

    def message
    if (newIndustry != null) {
        if (newIndustry.validate()) {
            newIndustry.save(flush: true)
            message = newIndustry.name + " has been saved"
        } else {
            message = newIndustry.name + " is not valid"
        }
    } else {

        message = "Insert a Industry"
    }

    return message
}
```

When running this test I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session :
```

The integration tests are running on the H2 test DB and the Rollback annotation has been included to removed the saved instances from the DB. I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this error as there should be nothing in the DB.